# Pulling user data using by Rest API with userID

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, rest

I am trying to pull logs belonging to a logged in user from my database. I think I have the id set-up correctly in the route however I am not sure where I am going wrong with the controller API. In Postman it is returning the catch error message and there are definitely entries in the database belonging to the user number.

I have tried a few variations but keep getting the same error. Is this the way my API is set-up

```
exports.userDiveLog = (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id;

    diveLog.findAll({
        where: {diverUserNumber: id}
    })
        .then(diveLog => {

            const userDiveLogList = [];
            for (i = 0; i < diveLog.length; i++) {
                userDiveLogList.push(diveLog[i].dataValues);
            }

            if (!userDiveLogList) {
                return res.status(404).send({ message: "No dive logs belonging to this user" });
            }

        res.status(200).send({
            data: userDiveLogList
        })
    })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving dive log belonging to user id= " + id
            });
        });
};
```

route

```
app.get('/api/divelog/userdiveloglist/:id', controller.userDiveLog);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Corrected as I hadn't properly inserted a try catch loop.

```
exports.userDiveLog = (req, res) => {

    try {
        const id = req.params.id;

        diveLog.findAll({
            where: {diverUserNumber: id}
        })
            .then(diveLog => {

                const userDiveLogList = [];
                for (i = 0; i < diveLog.length; i++) {
                    userDiveLogList.push(diveLog[i].dataValues);
                }

                if (!userDiveLogList) {
                    return res.status(404).send({message: "No dive logs belonging to this user"});
                }

                res.status(200).send({
                    data: userDiveLogList
                })
            })
    } catch(err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving dive log belonging to user id= " + id
            });
        }
};
```